# R: Speed up for loop

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

This is my R script with three nested `for` loops. It takes more than 2 minutes to finish 1 out of 2000 rounds of `for` loop. How to speedup this?

```
col<-NULL
row<-NULL
rep<-ncol(dat)-2
dist<-NULL
c1=3
for (i in 1:rep){
  c2=3
  for(j in 1:rep){
    r=1
    for (k in 1:nrow(dat)){
      p<-(dat[r,c1]-dat[r,c2])^2
      row<-rbind(row, p)
      r=r+1
    }
    row<-sqrt(sum(row))
    row1<-(1/(2*length(unique(dat[,1]))))*row
    col<-cbind(col, row1)
    c2=c2+1
    row<-NULL
  }
  dist<-rbind(dist,col)
  col<-NULL
  c1=c1+1
}
```

EDIT:

```
> head(dat)
  mark alle G1 G2 G3 G4 G5 G6 G7 G8 G9 G10 G11 G12 G13 G14 G15 G16 G17 G18 G19 G20 G21 G22 G23 G24
1   M1  228  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 0.0 0.5   0   0
2   M1  234  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0.5 0.5   1   1
3   M1  232  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0.0 0.0   0   0
4   M1  240  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0.0 0.0   0   0
5   M1  230  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0.5 0.0   0   0
6   M1  238  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0.0 0.0   0   0
```

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you gave an example of the `dat` data, as well as a brief description of what this code intends to do.

Comment: @Maxim.K: See my edit for `dat` file. This code calculates Modified Rogers Genetic distance from allele frequency data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the *Modified Rogers Genetic distance* but it looks like the euclidean distance multiplied by `1/(2*length(unique(dat$mark)))`:

```
f <- 1/(2*length(unique(dat$mark)))
d <- f*dist(t(dat[, -c(1, 2)]), method="euclidean")
```

Comment: You might want to add d <- as.matrix(d) to convert into an object that's easier to use after using the distance function

Comment: @ramesh: If this solves your problem, could you please accept the answer.

Comment: I think `dat[, -c(1, 2)]` should be transposed?

Comment: @MartinMorgan: yes, `dat[, -c(1,2)]` should be transposed.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest thing you can do to speed up the loop is to preallocate the vectors and matrices before the loops.  Then, instead of using `cbind()` and `rbind()`, add the results to the vectors/matrices like so:

```
# Was: row<-rbind(row, p)
row[k] <- p

# Was: col<-cbind(col, row1)
col[j] <- row1

# Was: dist<-rbind(dist,col)
dist[i, ] <- col
```

After that, you can explore ways to vectorize the operation or, better yet, see if there already exists a function to perform this task (or if the task is based on something for which there exists a function).  Further, anything that does not depend on the loop (such as `row1<-(1/(2*length(unique(dat[,1]))))`) should be moved out of the loop.  Otherwise you are just recalculating the same value over and over which negatively effects performance.

The key with loops is avoiding `rbind()` and `cbind()` by preallocating the vectors and matrices before the loop will provide a *lot* of performance boost.

Comment: He could also move `row1<-(1/(2*length(unique(dat[,1]))))` out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Although similar function already exists, I tried my own way. 
I removed one complete `for` loop, `rbind` and `cbind`. 
Now this takes only 124 seconds to write 1014 X 1014 matrix against 2 minutes for just one round of 1014 X 1014 matrix (means 1 X 1014).

```
dat<-read.table("alreq1.txt", sep="\t",header=T)
col<-NULL
row<-NULL
rep<-ncol(dat)-2
dist<-NULL
dist<- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = rep, ncol = rep))
m<-1/sqrt(2*length(unique(dat[,1])))
c1=3
for (i in 1:rep){
  c2=3
  for(j in 1:rep){
      p<-na.omit(dat[,c1]-dat[,c2])^2
      row<-sum(p)
      row<-sqrt(row)*m
      col[j] <- row
      c2=c2+1
      row<-NULL
      p<-NULL
  }
  dist[i,] <- col
  c1=c1+1
  col<-NULL
  }
```

Hopefully, still this code can be improved.